# Dynamically add an offset border to all images

Tags: css

I am looking to create this effect on all images within a WP article, where the image has a border, but another 'offset' border:

[image]

I cannot use pseudo elements on images, and I don;t want to use the 'outline' CSS property because of browser support, so is my only option JS? Or am I being thick?

Thanks all

Comment: Cannot add image for some reason :(

Comment: imgur has been hacked is why - using snaggy instead

Comment: i could'nt understand how this border will look like on your image , is there any example

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: Wrap the image and put a pseudo-element on the wrapper.

Comment: Sorry should have explained... It's a wordpress site and wrapping the image is not an option as the client will just insert an image and not understand wrapping or giving classes etc. thanks though

Comment: What's wrong with the outline property? http://caniuse.com/#feat=outline

Comment: Only supports IE11

I may end up using it, and fall back to no funky border in IE8

Comment: Ended up using JS

$( "img" ).wrap( "<div class='img-frame'></div>" );